# Apply Software Update to SharePoint and OWA server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, owa

I'm using WSUS to manage Microsoft update for SharePoint and OWA server. 
I'm confusing to choice the updates, WSUS shows me 2 options as images below:

i.e:

```
 Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB2760508)

 Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB2760508) farm-deployment
```

Which KB should I choose to approve?

[image]

[image]